# Ways to transcribe speech which language is not identified?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to build a software that will identify the language being spoken.
My plan is to use Google's cloud speech to text to transcribe the speech, and put it through cloud translation api to detect the langauge of the transcription.

However, since speech to text requires language code to be set prior to transcribing, I was planning to run it multiple times with different sets of languages and compare the "confidence" value to find the most confident transcription, that will be put through to cloud translation api.

Would this be the ideal way? Or would there be any other possible options?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the [Detecting language spoken automatically](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multiple-languages) page in google cloud speech documentation.

Comment: Yeah. I meant using this when I said "run it multiple times with different sets of languages".